# How can I change NumWorkers in parallel cluster profile when MATLAB starts?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, parallel-processing

I'm designing a `GUI` that use `parallel computing`. I want change `NumWorkers` in `parallel cluster profile` when my program starts and set it to `MATLAB` default value when i exit the program. How can i do that with coding?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `parcluster` command to get a 'cluster object' of which you can change the properties, like

```
c = parcluster
```

then

```
c.NumWorkers = 3;
```

You can save that number to the cluster profile with

```
saveProfile(c);
```